# Restore MBR when installation disk is missing

Tags: windows-vista, boot, mbr

One of our computers had a dual boot with Windows Vista and Ubuntu. I have removed the Linux partitions and Vista was running until I rebooted. Now it cannot boot anymore. Not a big issue as (I believe) you only need the install disk to repair the installation and restore the Master boot record. The only catch: I don't have the Vista install disk and I believe it never came with the computer. I do have a Windows 7 install disk, but that is 64 bit and the computer is 32 bit. I now remember I probably have some old MSDN disk with Vista on it, but I don't have them here.

The Vista installation is all right and I don't want to reinstall anything unless there is no other option. Can I download a tool somewhere and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to boot with your Win 7 CD and choose something like Repair System in installation step ?

Comment: I just found out that the system is 64 bit, and I just decided to install W7.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Spotmou bootsuit computer repair trial or from a certain "respectable site"

http://www.bootsuite.com/

You can burn it to a cd and start your computer and fix all kinds of problems

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.